# increasing size of circle in a radial gradient in CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have the following CSS rules for my gradient:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgb(237, 241, 254), rgb(195, 253, 237));
```

I was just wondering if I could somehow increase the size of the circle that contains the first colour. It seems that the colour is only restricted to a small area. Is this possible at all?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: increase the height of the container? I'm not quiet sure what you are really asking.. need some more info to help you better

Comment: Sorry, I've explained it a bit more and added an image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might  found a solution for you, please see both snippets:

**1st snippet just for comparison:**

```css
div {
  background: rgb(173, 217, 228);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 75%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1)), color-stop(75%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 75%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 75%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 75%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 75%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#add9e4', endColorstr='#f7fbfc', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  height: 400px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**2nd snippet with a bigger circle on the right/left - top/bottom**

```css
div {
  background: rgb(173, 217, 228);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 60%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 60%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 60%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 60%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(173, 217, 228, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 237, 242, 1) 60%, rgba(247, 251, 252, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#add9e4', endColorstr='#f7fbfc', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The difference from 1st to 2nd snippet is the location:

- 1st has `75%` or `color-stop(75%`
- 2nd has `60%` or `color-stop(60%`